# eclipse debug: Source not found for

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I know this is a frequently asked question, but i have been searching for a solution for my problem online since yesterday and have not been able to find any!

I am using Eclipse Helios with Tomcat 6.0.2, when ever I try to debug my code using the tomcat and eclipse i am getting the error `Source not found`, this is the case for even the code that i have wrote myself and not just all the jar files

I have the java build path set up correctly, I am also using jdk1.6.0 and have this set up correctly as well so that is not the problem, it does show the code when i am debugging if i right click on the debug console and go to `Edit Source Lookup...`. Because this will show the source code just for that run of the debugger, I when into `Run -> Debug Configurations` and in the `Java Application` window i set it up to work with Tomcat and in the `source` tab I added my project and all the jar files but this does not work either! when i debug again and go into the `Edit Source Lookup...` it does not show me the project and jar files that I have saved in there

Does anybody have any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem, well in a roundabout way. In my catalina.bat file I have added the line

`set JAVA_OPTS= -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5001,server=y,suspend=n %JAVA_OPTS%`

below where the `JAVA_OPTS` are set, this will listen on socket 5001 for any debug requests. Then in eclipse, under `Debug Configurations...` i created a new `Remote Java Application` and set the port to 5001 so that Tomcat would pick this up. Now when i start tomcat using `startup.bat`, when the code hits a breakpoint it opens in eclipse and I can debug like normal

Hope this helps others that have this problem

Answer (score 9):

Its actually very easy.Click on "Edit Source Look Path". You ll get the next popup where you need to click "Add"--> This gives another popup where you could click on "Java Project"---> THis leads to another popup where you can select your project which you are debugging and this is done! Hope this works fine.

[image]

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that I have done this but this is only a temporary fix as it only works for each individual time you are debugging so you have to do this everytime you want to debug

Comment: its ok, i actually managed to solve it in a roundabout way, i have added the answer.. thanks for the help anyway:)

Answer (score 0):

Can you debug code in other projects?
if you don't know, create a new dummy project and try to debug it

if you still get source not found for all projects, then download a fresh copy of eclipse, link it to a fresh copy of tomcat and add your dummy project to see if this work.
Hope this helps

Comment: ya i it works in other projects, this is the only one that it does not